# Eclipse (on my macbook) not detecting android tablet

Tags: android, eclipse, tablet, detection

I just installed Eclipse and all the plug ins related for Android App Development from here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html. I followed the instructions for creating my first app, the "Hello World App." The app works on the emulator, but I want to download it onto my new android tablet. But after following the instructions on this page: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html, I have had no luck. When I click the green and white play button, I am told to select a running Android device, but my Hipstreet Titan 2 HD tablet (Android Version: 4.4.2) does not show up. There is nothing to select on the page. How can I get my Titan 2 to be detected? I have the developer options there in settings and "USB debugging" is on as is "Verify apps over USB." Nothing else in the developer options in checked. What should I do? Thanks.

Comment: Does your computer recognize the tablet? Can you take files off of it while it is connected to the computer?

Comment: Sounds like you might need to install the driver for your table on your PC.

Comment: Couple things: 1. Open your command prompt and type "adb devices" and hit enter. Is anything listed? If not.. 2. Try changing your USB mode to "Camera (PTP)" if it's not already.

Comment: I am using a Macbook. Sorry forgot to add that.

Comment: My operating system is OS X 10.9.3

Answer (score 0):

This is an option that Alex Lockwood gives that worked for me on my Nexus 5.

"If you are developing with Windows, you might need to install the USB driver for our device. For Windows 7, here's how you do it:

To install the Android USB driver on Windows 7 for your device:

Connect your Android-powered device to your computer's USB port.
Right-click on Computer from your desktop or Windows Explorer, and select Manage.
Select Devices in the left pane.
Locate and expand Other device in the right pane.
Right-click the device name (such as Nexus S) and select Update Driver Software. This will launch the Hardware Update Wizard.
Select Browse my computer for driver software and click Next.
Click Browse and locate the USB driver folder. (The Google USB Driver is located in \extras\google\usb_driver.)
Click Next to install the driver."